# how to remove a UIView from the collision behavior in swift

Tags: swift

I have been programming a Break Out app for my swift class and I have been able to figure out everything except for how to remove one of the top paddles from the collision behavior. If someone could tell me how to remove something from the collisionBehavior's array of items, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please include any relevant code.  Or at least a lot more specifics/details.  As your question currently sits, it's rather broad.

Answer (score 0):

Set the dynamic flag to false?

> The default value is YES. If the value is NO, the physics body ignores all forces and impulses applied to it. This property is ignored on edge-based bodies; they are automatically static.

[SKPhysicsBody Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic)

Comment: I guess you wanted that to be a comment. :)

Comment: I know, that's why I thought you had something in mind, other that what I saw before. ;) I would vote up, but I have reached limit.

Comment: I did now, hope you didn't get my comment here wrong.